# SQL to skip max row on condition

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, max, hiveql

I need to return latest available row but on conditions.
Since Hive doesn't support PL-T/SQL I need to work on functions.

Current code selects latest record only and doesn't take `ACTIVE_F` into consideration.

```
WITH CTE AS 

(select 
ID, 
myuser_insert_time as insert_time,
max(myuser_insert_time) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) as rn
from tbl1)

SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE rn =  insert_time
```

My data:

```
MYUSER_INSERT_TIME        ACTIVE_F
2019-06-14 15:00:32.000   6
2019-03-06 15:54:22.000   0
2019-01-25 08:43:45.000   1
2018-12-13 09:49:50.000   0
2018-11-24 10:11:06.000   0
2018-11-06 12:17:34.000   1
2018-07-04 16:59:15.000   0
2018-05-29 12:22:15.000   1
2018-05-24 20:19:00.000   2
2018-05-24 20:19:00.000   2
```

Expected behaviour:

1. Find latest record (done)
2. Check ACTIVE_F (When 6 - move to the next row and return that row, else proceed to next row)

Desired result:

```
MYUSER_INSERT_TIME        ACTIVE_F
2019-03-06 15:54:22.000   0
```

Comment: `...from tbl1 where ACTIVE_F <>6` ?

Comment: do u have any column in the table to be used in `order by` clause?

Comment: @Serg - I can't just eliminate `6` as it might be the only record for some cases.

Comment: @Shu - yes, `MYUSER_INSERT_TIME`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order rows conditionally by ACTIVE_F so 6's go after all other values

```
WITH CTE AS 

(select 
ID, 
myuser_insert_time as insert_time,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY case ACTIVE_F when 6 then 1 else 0 end,  eendmyuser_insert_time desc) as rn
from tbl1)

SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: I think we got it! I will test on sample results and let you know!

Comment: This works perfectly! I extended `CASE` in `ORDER BY` to accomodate one more flag that has to be iterated in second place. `ORDER BY case ACTIVE_F when 6 then 1 when 0 then 1 else 0 end,  eendmyuser_insert_time desc`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to just want to filter out `active_f = 6`, if I understand correctly.  You should do this *before* calculating the max insert time; that is, in the CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select ID, myuser_insert_time as insert_time,
             max(myuser_insert_time) over (partition by ID) as max_myuser_insert_time
      from tbl1
      where active_f <> 6
    )
select * 
from CTE 
where myuser_insert_time = insert_time;
```

Your `max()` also had an `order by` column, so you were taking a cumulative `max()`.  This is not necessary.  The `order by` is unnecessary (even if the code worked).

EDIT:

If you need "6" if it is the only row, then use `row_number()` and make it the last row:

```
with cte as (
      select ID, myuser_insert_time as insert_time,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case when active_f = 6 then 2 else 1 end),
                                         myuser_insert_time desc
                               ) as rn
      from tbl1
    )
select * 
from CTE 
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately eliminating `6` is not a workaround here. There might be a case when only one row exists - which has `6`.If he is the only one then he should be displayed.

Comment: @marcin2x4 . . . I don't think that is clear in the question.

Comment: I'll re-iterate. I need to find first latest row that appears after row with `ACTIVE_F = 6`. If second row is also `6` - continue the loop.

Comment: @marcin2x4 . . . That is what the edited code does.

Comment: `order by (case when active_f = 6 then 2 else 1 end), myuser_insert_time DESC` - `DESC` fixes the issue as I need latest (insert time) record :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `case when active_f =6 then 1 else 0 end` to the `order by` clause of the analytic function. Records with active_f !=6 will be preferred. Also use row_number and order by myuser_insert_time desc:

```
WITH CTE AS 

(select 
ID, 
myuser_insert_time as insert_time,
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY myuser_insert_time desc, case when active_f =6 then 1 else 0 end) as rn
from tbl1)

SELECT * FROM CTE 

WHERE rn =  1
```

Comment: Almost there. I need second latest row.